# Using openlayers lib, the same point show in different places between different layers

Tags: google-maps, openlayers, projection

On [this demo](http://sunsetsunrising.com/openlayers/mine/index-debug.html) there are three layers:

1. `MyLayer`: using custom tile data
2. `Google`: using `Openlayer.Layer.Google` v3 API
3. `TMS`

When I put three markers on the map, shows different places after switching different layers. I've already change Google'layers projection to Openlayers default projection `EPSG:4326`.

How can I fix this problem?

and also why?

Coordinates of three points are:

- `(0, 0)`
- `(31.22689446881399, 121.475830078125)`
- `(18.255436745247998, 109.51309204101562)`

all [my code is from here](https://github.com/lizzie/openlayers/blob/master/mine/assets/map/src/map.js#L94)

Waiting for answers and thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a layer like Google or OSM, you have to set the default projection to `EPSG:900913` and not to `EPSG:4326`. Then you should reproject all your layers to the mercator projection.

You can read more documentation about spherical mercator [here](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/spherical_mercator.html).
You can also search for `mercator` on this [example page](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/)